# How to mark a library as an Obsolete Gradle Dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

During the Android Lint analysis, I see notifications of obsolete dependencies like Gson, or the Android build tools.

As a publisher of my own library can I piggy back on this functionality to help notify consumers a new versions of the libraries I publish is available?

Comment: There's the `NewerVersionAvailable` option, but the user of your library has to enable it either from command line when running lint or in their build.gradle lint config.

Comment: Hmm is that doesn't seem to work with my maven configuration, which has a latest version within it https://bintray.com/artifact/download/onedrive/Maven/com/onedrive/sdk/onedrive-sdk-android/maven-metadata.xml